# Align Text and photos

Tags: html, css, sass

Ok, so I searched for hours on Google how to align these two objects differently but without any luck.
I want the pictures to be on the left side and text to be on the right side.
Align="" didn't really do anything.
This is the section in HTML:

```
 <section class="site-section about-us-section" id="about-us-section">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row mb-5 pt-0 site-section">
      <div class="col-md-6 align-self-center">
        <h3 class="section-title-sub text-primary">About Us</h3>
        <h2 class="section-title mb-4">More Details On</h2>

        <p>Soluta quasi cum delectus eum facilis recusandae nesciunt molestias accusantium libero dolores repellat id in dolorem laborum ad modi qui at quas dolorum voluptatem voluptatum repudiandae.</p>
        <p>Soluta quasi cum delectus eum facilis recusandae nesciunt molestias accusantium libero dolores repellat id in dolorem laborum ad modi qui at quas dolorum voluptatem voluptatum repudiandae.</p>
        <p class="mt-4"><a href="#" class="spepcial_link">Read more about us</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 ml-auto img-overlap">
        <div class="img-1"><img src="images/sq_img_6.png" alt="Image" class="img-fluid img-shadow"></div>
        <div class="img-2"><img src="images/sq_img_10.png" alt="Image" class="img-fluid img-shadow"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here's a picture of the current situation:
[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFInR.png)

I hope you guys can help me solve it.

Thanks.

Comment: We need to see your CSS as well. Learn [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Flex-box for this. `flex-flow:row-reverse` property place elements in reverse order.
Hope this helps.
Let me know if any queries.

```css
.site-section{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-flow: row-reverse;
    align-items: baseline;
}

.align-self-center{
  width:80%;
}

.img-overlap{
  width:20%;
}
```

```html
<section class="site-section about-us-section" id="about-us-section">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row mb-5 pt-0 site-section">
      <div class="col-md-6 align-self-center">
        <h3 class="section-title-sub text-primary">About Us</h3>
        <h2 class="section-title mb-4">More Details On</h2>

        <p>Soluta quasi cum delectus eum facilis recusandae nesciunt molestias accusantium libero dolores repellat id in dolorem laborum ad modi qui at quas dolorum voluptatem voluptatum repudiandae.</p>
        <p>Soluta quasi cum delectus eum facilis recusandae nesciunt molestias accusantium libero dolores repellat id in dolorem laborum ad modi qui at quas dolorum voluptatem voluptatum repudiandae.</p>
        <p class="mt-4"><a href="#" class="spepcial_link">Read more about us</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 ml-auto img-overlap">
        <div class="img-1"><img src="images/sq_img_6.png" alt="Image" class="img-fluid img-shadow"></div>
        <div class="img-2"><img src="images/sq_img_10.png" alt="Image" class="img-fluid img-shadow"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you very much you helped me a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Use flex to create '2-columns' layout by setting the direct parent of those 2 elements. I removed some divs to simplify the code, it also looks like over using divs.

```
 <section class="site-section about-us-section" id="about-us-section">

      <div class="col-md-6 align-self-center">
        <h3 class="section-title-sub text-primary">About Us</h3>
        <h2 class="section-title mb-4">More Details On</h2>
        <p>Soluta quasi cum delectus eum facilis recusandae nesciunt molestias accusantium libero dolores repellat id in dolorem laborum ad modi qui at quas dolorum voluptatem voluptatum repudiandae.</p>
        <p>Soluta quasi cum delectus eum facilis recusandae nesciunt molestias accusantium libero dolores repellat id in dolorem laborum ad modi qui at quas dolorum voluptatem voluptatum repudiandae.</p>
        <p class="mt-4"><a href="#" class="spepcial_link">Read more about us</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 ml-auto img-overlap">
        <div class="img-1"><img src="images/sq_img_6.png" alt="Image" class="img-fluid img-shadow"></div>
        <div class="img-2"><img src="images/sq_img_10.png" alt="Image" class="img-fluid img-shadow"></div>
      </div>
</section>

#about-us-section {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.align-self-center {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Flexbox is perfect for those cases.
Check this pen - https://codepen.io/orby32/pen/MWYLaap?editors=1100

Comment: I need to wrap the two elements with <div class=" "> and then use what you wrote in the CSS?

Comment: No, just paste that in your css. I used there an exist doc.

Comment: I did and it just separated the two pictures I used, I aligned them right and it did the desired overlap that you can see in the photo but I want to change between them  I need to write the text in Hebrew so it has to be aligned to the right and the photos to the left. Wrapping them together won't help me I think, because I need to move each one of them.